# How can I read a set of bytes from a file and convert them to letters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

I am trying to read text from a file which contains a series of bytes, and want to convert them back to letters/numbers to be used again. I have found no suitable method of doing this upon searching StackOverflow or Google. To show what I mean, here is my code:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("test.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
System.out.println("From File: " + lineFromFile);

OUTPUT:
```

`From File: [78, 97, 109, 101, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 99, 97, 114, 100, 78, 111, 32, 54, 55, 56, 56, 55, 53, 55, 49, 57, 32, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 32, 66, 97, 108, 97, 110, 99, 101, 32, 51, 55, 48, 32, 111, 118, 101, 114, 100, 114, 97, 102, 116, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 32, 111, 118, 101, 114, 68, 114, 97, 102, 116, 76, 105, 109, 105, 116, 32, 48, 32, 112, 105, 110, 32, 50, 53, 50, 53]`

These bytes represent letters/numbers which I had encoded previously before writing them to the file from another `Java` program.

**What have I tried?**

```
byte[] bytes = lineFromFile.split("\\s+");
String fileToString= new String(bytes, UTF_8);
System.out.println("text: " + fileToString);
```

The error given:

```
error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to byte[]
      byte[] bytes = text.split("\\s+");
                               ^
```

If anyone could suggest a way to do this or maybe even a better method of encoding which is easier to decode once read from a file, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Your file does not actually contain a series of bytes; it contains a series of comma-separated integer numbers encoded as ASCII text. How did you encode them in your program that wrote them?

Comment: @yole I used `byte[] bytes = details.getBytes(UTF_8);` details being the `String` of numbers/letters and `UTF_8` being a charset.

Comment: refer this link: http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/character-file-reading-writing.jsp

Comment: you are using split() instead of this use getBytes() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote the characters, as number as text, not binary.  You need to read those numbers as text and convert them back into characters.

```
String lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
// strip out the `[` and `]`
lineFromFile = lineFromFile.substring(1, lineFromFile.length()-1);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s: lineFromFile.split(", "))
    sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(s));
String text = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`split()` returns String array. Use `lineFromFile.getBytes()` it returns you sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Open a FileInputStream to the file that you’ve stored the Object to.
    Open a ObjectInputStream to the above FileInpoutStream.
    Use readObject method of ObjectInputStream class to read the Object from the file.
    The above method returns an Object of type Object. So you have to cast it to the original type to use it properly.

import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

    public class ObjectIOExample {

        private static final String filepath="C:\\....obj";

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            ObjectIOExample objectIO = new ObjectIOExample();

            //Read object from file
            Student st = (Student) objectIO.ReadObjectFromFile(filepath);
            System.out.println(st);
        }

        public Object ReadObjectFromFile(String filepath) {

            try {

                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filepath);
                ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

                Object obj = objectIn.readObject();

                System.out.println("The Object has been read from the file");
                objectIn.close();
                return obj;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```